# Using artifactory in gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I want to use an artifactory in gradle. To be more specific, i want to use 4 customized  jars that are not in the maven repository. So i'd like them to be at the artifactory server and will be downloaded when needed.

Do i need to install something other than "Gradle eclipse integration" ?

Can someone give me an example on how to do that in the gradle.build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to deploy those jars to Artifactory.
Probably, [using the UI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Artifacts) will be the easiest way to go.

Next, you need to declare Artifactory as your repository. You can do it by using the standard `repositories` clause (as @lance-java suggested), or by using Artifactory Gradle plugin. Probably the easiest will be generating the build script snippet from Artifactory itself.

Last will be adding the dependencies to your script. You can navigate to the jars you uploaded in the tree browser, and copy the snippets of dependency declarations from there.

Both steps are documented in [the User Guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Gradle) as well.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: i uploaded the jar and tried what @Lance-Java said.  but the jar wont download. this is my url (changed names) : http://teamname_artifactory:8081/artifactory    (with http://..)

Comment: When i try to use the gradle plugin ( generating the build script from artifactory) i get the following error:  Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
repositories {
   maven {
       url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.foo.mycompany:dep1:1.0"
    compile "com.foo.mycompany:dep2:1.0"
    compile "com.foo.mycompany:dep3:1.0"
    compile "com.foo.mycompany:dep4:1.0"
}
```

Comment: but the jars are now only locally, i compile it as "compile name: 'myjar' " (and i added a 'flatDir' to repositories...)